# Python subprocess piping to stdin

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin, popen

I'm trying to use python Popen to achieve what looks like this using the command line.

```
 echo "hello" | docker exec -i $3 sh -c 'cat >/text.txt'
```

The goal is to pipe the "hello" text into the `docker exec` command and have it written to the docker container.

I've tried this but can't seem to get it to work.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(('docker', 'exec', '-i', 'nginx-ssl', 'sh', '-c', 'cat >/text.txt'), stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('Hello')
p.stdin.close()
```

Comment: How does it fail to work? Does it produce an empty file? No file at all? An error message?

Comment: No file at all. No errors though.

Comment: What is "docker"? Do you have a link to its documentation?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: Just a hint (since I do not have docker installed): 1) use `communicate('Hello')` instead of `stdin.write` and do not close stdin.  Also, verify you have write privileges on the root directory, if not try replacing `>/text.txt` with `>text.txt`.

Comment: Perfect `communicate('Hello')` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `stdin` the new line also:

```
p.stdin.write('Hello\n')
```

That is the same thing even with `sys.stdout`.  You don't need to give `print` a new line because it does that for you, but any writing to a file that you do manually, you need to include it.  You should use `p.communicate('Hello')` instead, though.  It's made for that.